# Wrong visual display of QPropertyAnimation

Tags: qt, qpropertyanimation

I decided to animate my application in Qt 6.4.0, for this I use QPropertyAnimation and QGraphicsOpacityEffect. But when overlaying, a failure occurs and the elements visually shift. And the buttons themselves remain in place.
The effect appears after 1 page change QStackedWidget.
Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DszOG.png)
After:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV3e4.png)
QPropertyAnimation implementation:

```
void MainWindow::animationopacity()
{
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
    ui->stackedWidgetMenu->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
    QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff,"opacity");
    a->setDuration(350);
    a->setStartValue(0);
    a->setEndValue(1);
    a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);
    a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

This function is called after each click of QPushButton in the menu

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonAnalytics_clicked()
{
    ui->stackedWidgetMenu->setCurrentIndex(1);
    animationopacity();
}
```

I tried to change layers and shapes, apply eff to other elements, the behavior does not change.

Comment: The current code you're sharing does not seem to affect your widgets positions, please try to isolate the ui from your project with only the code responsible for manipulating it. The result should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is necessary for your question to receive a valid answer.